# How to setup git server which combined with other remote repository?

Tags: git

I want to build up a git server which provider source management on the project which is related to other project using git.

For example, i checkout linux mainstream code, and made some modifications, which are just like new machine ports, on the code.
i want to use git to manage this modified code. at the same time, i want to merge the mainstream code in sometimes.

btw, i would also modify the mainstream code. they are not seperated.

i must try to explain it. there is another thing i havn't noticed. i want to setup a remote server in order to manage the code have been modified, or the whole source tree.

how to solve that problem?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a problem. The use case you described is exactly what git is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the Linux mainstream repo, make a branch which you can:

- update by making your additions (new port)
- update by making your modification (in the existing code)
- **[rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)** on top of the master branch (which track Linux code mainstream master branch) once in a while, in order to include in *your* branch any new remote development.

Comment: I think i did not describe it clearly.
i try it again here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767980/how-to-merge-two-remote-repository