# Merging two remote repositories in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to merge two remote repositories in Git.

One is mainstream repository, which I do not have write permission. I want to track its master branch.

The other is maintained by us, I have full rights on it.

I want to track the mainstream code. At the same time, our modification would be recorded in my remote repository.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I would recommend:

- cloning `yourRemoteRepo` (that way, you can easily pull/push from that repo)
- adding `mainstreamRepo` as a remote and fetch its branch, then track the one which interest you

  ```
  git clone git://yourRemoteRepo
  git remote add mainStreamRepo http://mainStreamRepo
  git fetch mainStreamRepo
  git checkout -b mainStreamMaster mainStreamRepo/master
  git checkout master
  ```

From there, you can

- merge `mainStreamMaster` to your `master`,
- or rebase your `master` on top of `mainStreamMaster` (in order to integrate the full history of `mainStreamMaster` into your `master` branch)
- then make some evolutions to `master` (or to a topic-specific branch) that you can push to `yourRemoteRepo`.

Comment: @TravisCunningham (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2487332/travis-cunningham) thank you for the edit ([incorrectly rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2317758)): I have added the name of the remote I initially forgot.

Comment: Is this possible w/o clone but only fetch and then merging on the remote references? Or does merging always require a checked out working directory?

Comment: @hakre yes, merging involves a working tree where a branch is checked out. So a clone is involved as well.

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast reply. For Fast-Forward "merges" (better: reset) this could work, but I should verify first if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

Comment: with your branch pulled from remote you can push to either origin i.e. `git push mainStreamRepo HEAD:master` or `git push origin`

Comment: @Daniel That is true indeed. In the context of this question, though, that would not be possible (since one of the two repositories is read-only)