# How to combine two separate git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository

I have a local copy a of a web project on a local server. Everything is ok. Works with git and github.

However I have the (almost) same repository on another server. The problem is that repo is initialised with its own `git init` command and thus the two repos are separate.

Is there any way to sync these?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6204133/877115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this successfully

```
git remote add upstream git://another-server.com/repo.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```