# Merge two different repositories into one and preserving the history

Tags: git, github

I cloned *and* forked a repository from here source: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps resulting in two different repositories.

`Clone Repo:` https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1 (repo 1)

`Fork Repo:` https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps (repo 2)

Now I want to merge the `Clone Repo` (repo 1) into the `Fork Repo` (repo 2), preserving history if possible. Is that even possible?

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767980/merging-two-remote-repositories-in-git). When I try to merge the `Clone repo`(repo 1) into the `Forked Repo`(repo 2) I get the error

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Have you tried to `git pull fork-origin master`?

Comment: @YagoAzedias ehm could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two remote repositories in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767980/merging-two-remote-repositories-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Add "repo1" as a remote and merge it into "repo2"

You can just added the repo1 as a new remote and them merge it into your local repository:

1. Clone the fork https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps

   `git clone https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps && cd react-native-maps`
2. Add a new remote to your local repository

   `git remote add repo1-origin https://github.com/Stophface/react-native-maps-0.20.1`
3. Merge the content from remote `repo1-origin` into your local fork (repo2)

   `git pull repo1-origin [branch-name]`

OBS: Both of a rebase or a simple merge will preserve your git history, but if you want to preserve the commits chronology in your `git log`, I recommend you to do rebase:

- `git pull --rebase repo1-origin [branch-name]`

That way you will merge the two contents

Comment: Does that preserve History?

Comment: I think not, it will appear in your `git log` as a Merge. I'm not totally sure, but I think that if you want to preserve the commits history you have to do a rebase

Comment: @DietrichEpp But how do I preserve the commits history in my `git log` ?

Comment: Yago: Merge preserves history in `git log`.  If you look at `git log`, it will show the history of *both* branches. If you use `git log --graph`, it will show you more explicitly, or you can use something like gitk / gitx / etc. to get a graphical history.